# Typescript: how to add index signature inside Array.map function arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a library function which returns an array of objects:

```
function someLibraryFunc(): object[]
```

I need to access a property of type string inside the returned objects, but the compiler is complaining:

```
function myFunc(prop: string): string[] {
   someLibraryFunc()
      .map(obj => obj[prop] as string) // <-- compiler error
}

/*
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
*/
```

I've tried to add index signature like so:

```
function myFunc(prop: string): string[] {
   someLibraryFunc()
      .map((obj: { [key: string]: string }) => obj[prop]) // <-- compiler error
}

/* 
TS2345: Argument of type '(obj: { [key: string]: string; }) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => string'.   
Types of parameters 'obj' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.       
Index signature is missing in type '{}'.
*/
```

I've tried also the following:

```
function myFunc(prop: string): string[] {
   someLibraryFunc()
      .map((obj: { [key: string]: string }, index: number, array: object[]) => obj[prop]) // <-- compiler error
}

/* 
TS2345: Argument of type '(obj: { [key: string]: string; }) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => string'.   
Types of parameters 'obj' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.       
Index signature is missing in type '{}'.
*/
```

What is the proper way to add index signature to the arguments in the map function?

Comment: What do you expect `myFunc("somePropertyNotPresentInReturnedObjects")` to output?   The typing of `myFunc()` says that needs to produce a `string[]`, but I expect you're going to get an `undefined[]` at runtime.  Do you have some desired constraint on `prop` that you haven't mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to explicitly assert that the `prop` is really the key of `object`:

```
declare function someLibraryFunc(): object[]

function myFunc(prop: string): string[] {
    return someLibraryFunc()
        .map(obj => obj[prop as keyof typeof obj] as string)
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=60&pln=5&pc=50#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwGccBbEAGSwCMZYBPAMTTAAoBKALnh0oCtwMA2gF0AsAChxKdNjzxiDJswAOMHEs4EMMLKgDmHQlp27h8AN7j4V%20HAzIY%20IqQrU6jdG0vXvAOmJQlZm4eeABeAD4uXgEVNXgoAngAaxBaHER4DFolEHSoniF4xM1tPVZxAF8gA)

Answer (score 2):

The typing of these functions depend on the `Array<T>` interface, so you can cast the type returned by `someLibraryFunc()` instead:

```
(someLibraryFunc() as { [key: string]: string }[])
       .map(obj => obj[prop])
```

If possible you'd want more specific types defined for your function in the first place though.

Comment: I don't think you need that intervening `as unknown` in there.